# Verilog - натуральное число X транслирует Y=\floor{x/3}

Tags: binary, конечные-автоматы, verilog

Система (мили, не мор) получает натуральное число `X` и транслирует натуральное число `Y` так, чтобы: `Y=\floor{x/3}` когда `floor` - целая часть.

Мне нужно написать программу в *Verilog* с помощью конечного автомата, который я нарисовал:

[image: схема автомата]

У системы есть еще `input reset` и если `reset==1`, то будет `output==0`

С чего мне начать?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала опишите вашу программу, то есть укажите входы и выходы, например

```
module my_project(
input1,
input2,
output1
)
```

где input1, input2, output1 - это порты Вашего блока, по которым вы получаете данные.
Далее необходимо описать каждый из портов, например:

```
input  input1; 
input [15:0] input2; 
output [3:0] output1;
reg [3:0] output1;
```

Замечу, что один из портов я указал как регистр. После этого начинается непосредственное описание логики Вашей программы. Вам необходимо определить собираетесь ли вы реализовывать синхронную схему или асинхронную. Если Вы не уверены, что понимаете о чем я, лучше всего почитать различную литературу на тему языков описания аппаратуры, например различные книги от Pong Chu или Харрис и Харрис Архитектура компьютера.